# Turn each child of a selector into a row in my table

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a `div` that has multiple `uls`. Each `ul` has a button that goes with it. When a user clicks a button I'd like to remove the `ul`, its `siblings`, and its `parent` from the main `div` then create a `table` that represents the removed `ul` such that the item name and quantity from each `li` is displayed as a row in the `table` then append the `table` to a secondary `div`.

[Here's what I have so far](http://jsfiddle.net/akulkarni143/ep07cuLr/)

As I have it now, if a `ul` has multiple `lis`, all of the item names and quantities are displayed in a single row.

Here is [full screen result.](http://jsfiddle.net/akulkarni143/ep07cuLr/embedded/)

**`Code:`**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.accptOrdr').click(function () {
        var text = $(this).closest('fieldset').children().first();
        console.log(text);
        var thisTr = text.parent();
        var itemName = $(this).parent().prev().find('.list-group-item').justtext();
        var badgeHTML = $("<div/>").append($(this).parent().prev().find('.badge').clone()).html();
        var result = $("<div/>").append('<br>');
        /*var finalResult = badgeHTML + result;*/
        /*var result = badgeHTML.add('<br/>');   
            var finalResult = result.appendTo('result')*/
        console.log($('.table.accepted-orders'));
        $('.accepted-orders').append('<div class="well well-sm order col-md-5" style="width: 48%; height: 280px;"><div>Time remaining: 20 minutes</div> <div class="pull-left">' + text.html() + '</div><table class="table table-striped table-bordered"><thead><tr><th>Item</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Note</th></tr></thead><tr><td>  ' + itemName + '</td> <td> ' + badgeHTML + '  </td> </tr> </table> <div class="pull-right"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btns">Ready</button> </div></div>');
        $('#nwOrd3').remove();
        $(".btns").click(function () {
            alert("Food is ready");
        });
    });
});
jQuery.fn.justtext = function () {
    return $(this).clone()
        .children()
        .remove()
        .end()
        .text();
};
```

**How can I fix it so the item name and quantity from each `li` is displayed as a separate row in the `table`?**

Comment: you should re-title your question. It only has meaning to you. No one browsing is going to know what your question is about. Just a tip

Comment: @DelightedD0D: Can you `re-title` it for me? I'm not getting anything

Comment: Sure, as soon as I figure out what you're asking, lol. Readin gthrough the code now

Comment: So, if i'm in your jsfiddle, and I click accept on all of the new orders and it looks like this http://prntscr.com/8auzkf, what do you expect the right side look like?

Comment: I expect `quantity` to appear properly on right side. They aren't appearing properly

Comment: Yes, but what is "properly"? Is the quantity with the wrong elements?

Comment: It is appearing `side by side`. I want food item and quantity to appear in same line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88339/discussion-between-delightedd0d-and-ajay-kulkarni).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an order has multiple items, to make it so each item has its own row in the resulting table, you need to get the elements and iterate over them rather than jset getting the text from the parent:

#### [Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ep07cuLr/y/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.accptOrdr').click(function () {
        var fieldset = $(this).closest('fieldset');
        var text = fieldset.children().first();
        var lis= fieldset.find('li');
        var items = [];
        lis.each(function(){
            var itemName = $(this).justtext();
            var qty = $(this).find('.badge').text();
            var note = ''; // get some note here?
            var badge = '<span class="badge pull-right">'+qty+'</span>'
            items.push('<tr><td>'+itemName+'</td><td>'+badge+'</td><td>'+note+'</td></tr>' )
        });
        var result = $("<div/>").append('<br>');
        $('.accepted-orders').append('<div class="well well-sm order col-md-5" style="width: 48%; height: 280px;"><div>Time remaining: 20 minutes</div> <div class="pull-left">' + text.html() + '</div><table class="table table-striped table-bordered"><thead><tr><th>Item</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Note</th></tr></thead>'+items.join('')+'</table> <div class="pull-right"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btns">Ready</button> </div></div>');
        fieldset.parent().remove();
        $('.accepted-orders').children().last().find(".btns").click(function () {
            alert("Food is ready");
        });
    });
});
```